# Tolerance for or to

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct statement: adopt zero tolerance "for" or "to" discrimination in the workplace?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the sentence to make *tolerate* the main verb:

> Under our new policy, [name of company] *will not tolerate* discrimination in the workplace, including but not limited to: [list of examples].

Italics highlight the recommended verb form; square brackets indicate variables to fill in.

Comment: I don't know why you've been downvoted here. This is a good example of improving the sentence by slightly modifying its structure. Although it may not be a direct answer to the question, one could argue that the options presented by OP were not as strong as they could be.

Answer (score 1):

Either of the two choices would work, with a preference for "for". Although you didn't ask about it, "of" would also work, and probably would be second, after "for", before "to".

Comment: *of* may not work in the given context, though.

Comment: Hard to tell, with the quantity of given context provided.

Answer (score 0):

'Towards' is commonly used in this context. But you'd say something like 'We've adopted a zero tolerance approach towards...'